# Why does font-family=monospace not render the text with a non-proportinal font?

Tags: css, browsers, fonts

When I open the following HTML document in Chrome …

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
  p { font-family: monospace }
</style>
 
</head>
<body>

  <p>mmmmmmm</p>
  <p>iiiiiii</p>

</body>
```

… it is rendered like so

[image]

My understanding is that text with `font-family: monospace` should be rendered in a non-proportional font.

When I search for monospaced fonts on my system, I find some that I have installed:

```
$ fc-list :spacing=mono
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf: Liberation Mono:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationMono-Bold.ttf: Liberation Mono:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf: Liberation Mono:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationMono-Italic.ttf: Liberation Mono:style=Italic
```

**Update**: When I check the developer tools's *element tab*, I find the following information:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try: font-family: monospace, monospace;

Comment: @Steve, this doesn't have any noticeable effect.

Comment: In Chrome, click on the three dots at upper right, go to More tools, Developer tools, and check the Elements tab. See the Styles panel at right to see exactly what font is being displayed.

Comment: The font being displayed *is* `monospace` (see updated question).

Comment: Try this. Put this in the head: <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: I've added these `<meta>` tags,but I still have the same rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the following setting in Chrome which allows to specfiy a font for *Fixed-width font*. This setting was set to *Monospace*. After changing it to *Liberation Mono*, the monospaced fonts are also displayed "correctly".

[image]